# Nginx locatioin regex parent, child and proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

Need help writing correct `location` regex for my nginx proxy.

`location /` is proxying to external website

but a couple of paths are proxied to the local static site that has the following directory tree:

```
├── index.html
└── parent
    ├── child-1
    │   └── index.html
    ├── child-2
    │   └── index.html
    └── index.html
```

I need
`/parent/` to serve `parent/index.html`
`/parent/child-1/` to serve `parent/child-1/index.html`
`/parent/child-2/` to serve `parent/child-2/index.html`

however
`/parent/other-children` to be proxied to the external website under `location /`

Here is what I've tried:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://xyz$request_uri;
    }
    location ~ ^/parent/$ {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www/sites/dist;
    }
    location ~ ^/parent/(child-1|child-2) {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www/sites/dist;
    }
```

With this setup

`/parent/` works
`/parent/child-1` works
`/parent/child-2` works

`/parent/other-children` shows 404 Not Found

If anyone could help me to make /parent/other-children to proxy to the external server via `location /`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

To achieve the desired outcome one should use the `try_files` directive.

Here is the working example:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://xyz$request_uri;
    }

    location /parent/ {
        root /var/www/sites/dist;
        index index.html index.htm
    
        try_files $uri $uri/ /;
    }
```

`try_uri`

- first looks for the existence of the file that matches request URI `($uri)`
- if not found then it checks for the existence of the directory with the same name `($uri/)`
- If none is found then it proxies to the `location /`

For `try_uri` to work, one needs to specify the `root` folder where it will search for the files/directories. It also needs to know the default file to serve if the directory is found. For this, one should specify the `index` directive with the list of default files to serve in their priority order.